# Specifying UNIQUE constraints in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would appreciate your help with the blocker I have. I created a new table with the statement `CREATE TABLE copy_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table` because I wanted the second table with similar columns as the original table.

However, the second table came without the UNIQUE constraint that was in the original table. So far, I can insert data into the mentors' table but anything that required UNIQUE constraint is not working.

I tried to add the UNIQUE constraints but it's throwing this error: 
`syntax error at or near "UNIQUE"`

**Unedited code**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mentors AS SELECT users.user_id AS mentor_id, 
first_name, last_name, email, address, password, bio, occupation, expertise, is_mentor, is_admin FROM users;
```

**Edited code(Adding UNIQUE constraint)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mentors AS SELECT users.user_id AS mentor_id(UNIQUE),first_name, last_name, email, address, password, bio, occupation, expertise, is_mentor, is_admin FROM users;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) does not allow to define any constraints on the new table.

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) just after the table is created, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE mentors ADD UNIQUE(mentor_id)
```